# sklearn fit(x,y)-how can I use a list of x as x

Tags: scikit-learn

we ofen use fit(x,y) to train ,x is one line of df,how can I use multi line of df as x to train,and x is time based, multi line is also time based,is it possible ,how can I do it?

I just don't know how to do it

Comment: Perhaps if you showed more code (in a codeblock please - no images) it might be easier to understand the issue.  What are `x` and `y`? _"x is one line of df"_ ... a column in a pandas DataFrame?  I suspect that what you want to do is possible, I'm just not sure what you want to do and what your data looks like.

Comment: thanks for reply; \n  here is a x looks like: 20221215  0.37 0.65 0.36 0.48 in df,   I want to use  7 days of x to train but I don't know how can I do it

Comment: Would you edit your question and show `df.dtypes`, `df.head()`, and `df.describe(include="all")`?